# (Jira) Script Runner getCustomFieldValue ( get value without the html element)

Tags: groovy, jira-plugin

I want to get the value of a custom Jira field using the Groovy Script Runner. But when I run the following script in the Script Runner:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField

ComponentManager componentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance()
CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = componentManager.getCustomFieldManager()
CustomField cf= customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_10301") 
issue = componentManager.getIssueManager().getIssueObject("PM-72")

def value = issue.getCustomFieldValue(cf)
```

the result is:

```
<img src="/images/icons/priority_critical.gif"/> High
```

How do I get just the `High` without the html `<img>` element?

---

**UPDATE:** with help from @doelleri, I figured out that changing the last line in the script to this will work:

```
def value =  issue.getCustomFieldValue(cf).getValue().tokenize().last()
```

...but that certainly feels like a hack. Isn't there some built-in method to accomplish this? For example, if this weren't a custom field (like "Priority" for example), the code would be:

```
def value =  issue.getPriority().getString("name");
```

is there something comparable for custom fields?

Comment: `tokenize(' ').last()`

Comment: @doelleri: no, that returns error `tokenize() is not applicable for argument types: (com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.option.LazyLoadedOption)`

Comment: Unfortunately I think any solution is going to be a string manipulation hack, and the one proposed by @doelleri is as good as any

Comment: this is the most comprehensive guide iv'e seen so far:
http://labs.adaptavist.com/code/java/jira/2015/12/17/getting-custom-field-values-safely/